# Algebra & Artificial Intelligence (AI)

Tags: abstract-algebra, machine-learning, big-list, neural-networks, artificial-intelligence

**Artificial intelligence**, especially deep learning & neural networks for image processing and classfication, are related to **statistics** and **physics** e.g. as decribed in below papers.

**Statistics and AI**

[Simoncelli + Olshausen.Natural images statistics and neural representation](http://www.cns.nyu.edu/pub/eero/simoncelli01-reprint.pdf)

[Field.What the statistics of natural images tell us about visual coding](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/d8de/e1763268907dd1716a0ff3f9cdad64839319.pdf)

**Physics and AI**

A relation of deep learning and physics (renormalization group) is elaborated in:

[Mehta + Schwab.An exact mapping between the Variational Renormalization Group and Deep Learning](https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.3831)

Also category theory is used to describe neural systems and single aspects like e.g. back propagation.

**Category theory and AI**

[MSE - Category Theory & Artificial Intelligence (AI)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3126090/category-theory-artificial-intelligence-ai)

> **Question**. Are there interesting formulations and generalizations of (convolutional) neural networks (CNNs) / deep learning (or to machine learning in general) concepts in an algebraic context?

Fernando Martin-Maroto and Gonzalo G. de Polavieja published in 2018

[Martin-Maroto and Polavieja.Algebraic Machine Learning](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.05252.pdf)

See also the following pages

[Martin-Maroto and Polavieja et al.Algebraic AI](https://www.algebraic.ai/)

[YouTube.ALMA - Human Centric Algebraic Machine Learning](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=343axkMlCWk)

[European Commission.ALMA: Human Centric Algebraic Machine Learning](https://cordis.europa.eu/project/id/952091)

Clifford Neural Networks based on Clifford Algebras are subject in

[Hitzer et al.Applications of Clifford’s Geometric Algebra](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1305.5663.pdf)

mentioning **Clifford algebra neural computing**. However as far as I understand, this is more a generalization of neuron's in- and output values rather than an algebraic formulation of neural network related concepts?

In a similar direction(?) goes e.g.

[Bronstein et al.Geometric deep learning: going beyond Euclidean data](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.08097.pdf)

---

**Remark.** I am aware that this question could also be posted at stack overflow or some other stack exchange site. However my idea is that it could be better to ask it on the mathematics site, since it might rather be mathematicians that have some knowledge about such connections than e.g. computer scientists themselves.